# Updating data in jquery mobile using Django as backend

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have an running Django projects and a jquery mobile web-app to display content from the database. so far, all works fine. now i have a background task, which updates the DB, and to view the changes, i have to reload the page to see them. is there a possibility to update e.g. only the listview with the data, let's say every second?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WebSockets` to connect to a `node.js` server, then broadcast updates to a list of listeners when the data changes in the background process.

Read more :

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/
- http://socket.io

Comment: this could be one possibility, but the question is, does it work "out of the box". perhaps with jquery setInterval() or setTimeout() to periodicly fetch updates....!?

Comment: @oli I have never implemented this, I just tried to guide you to a possible solution.